# Add conditions where with 2 field conditions do not run accurately

Tags: sql

The data that appears does not match the conditions that have been applied

I implemented SQL code in the Navicat application, and have changed the structure of the code several times but it still doesn't work,
data that is not of ilart condition type
still appears

```
SELECT SERMAT,ILART,sum(GKSTP) as jumlah 
FROM swift_zab_iw39 
WHERE ILART='OVH' OR ILART='TST' and SERMAT='024147-000:09052'   
GROUP BY ILART,SERMAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parenthesis to the `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE (ILART = 'OVH' OR ILART = 'TST') AND SERMAT = '024147-000:09052'
```

Comment: In your case, using IN would give even cleaner code

Answer (score 2):

Use IN operator:

```
WHERE ILART IN('OVH','TST') AND SERMAT = '024147-000:09052'
```

Comment: @AbdulMUTIMF . . . This is the better solution.